# Hibernate insert into existing table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, db2

There is an existing table which consists manually inserted couple of records.
Let's assume by next record it inserted done by using hibernate. ex : first 3 records inserted manually and since 4th record it uses hibernate.

In the Entity class, primary key field annotated as @GeneratedValue and value is `GenerationType.IDENTITY`. For MySQL DB it worked fine and 4th record inserted without any issue,but same steps done in DB2 DB and issue come up as `constraintviolationexception`. I think newly record trying to insert with existing primary key by hibernate. Can anyone explain what is going on under the hood ? How dose MySQL DB inserted without any error ?

Comment: How did you create the DB2 table? With Hibernate `Entity` class or just created it manually and mapped the `Entity` class?

Comment: Hi @sachith.. it was created by hibernate.